# How to use Get-Content to get all information from the most recent file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use Get-Content to get the most recent .xml file and all its content to be displayed in the powershell window, but I am having a hard time.

I have use the the following:

```
Get-ChildItem "\\Server1\c$\Program Files\AAA\Logs\"  | Sort-Object CreationTime | Select-Object -Last 1

Get-Content -Path "\\Server1\c$\Program Files\AAA\Logs\" | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).addDays(-1)} | Select -Last 1
```

But I cannot figure out how to go about grabbing the latest file and displaying all its content in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. You have to pipe the result of your first line to `Get-Content`:

```
Get-ChildItem "\\Server1\c$\Program Files\AAA\Logs\" | Sort-Object CreationTime | Select-Object -Last 1 | Get-Content
```

---

Your second line does not make much sense. If you provide a valid path to `Get-Content`, it will return to you the content of the file as a string. You cannot apply any creation time logic to this content afterwards with `Where-Object`.

Your first line though, works like this:

1. It gets all files and folders that are contained in your given path. If this path really just contains valid log files, you can leave it like this. Otherwise you should filter this result, so you really just get your desired files. To be precise, `Get-ChildItem` returns an array of [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo) objects. They contain a lot of information about your files.
2. You then sort this array of [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo) objects by the `CreationTime` property with `Sort-Object`.
3. Finally, you select the last element of the sorted array. This is still a [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo) object. That's why you see some of its properties in your output.

If you then pipe this [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo) object to `Get-Content`, the `FullPath` property of this object will be mapped to the `-Path` parameter of `Get-Content`, thus returning the content of the file specified by the [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo) object.